# What the difference between the smallest two numbers from these numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There are infinitely many integers $n$ bigger than $1$, such that if we divide $n$ by any integer $k$ where $2\leq k\leq 11$, the remainder is equal  to $1$.

What the difference between the smallest two such integers?

Help guys please. this is my try, the smallest number will be $lcm+1$ $$= 2^3 * 3^2 * 5*7*11+1$$ and the next number will be $$2*lcm+1$$
the difference between them $=icm=27720$

Comment: Can you write down what you've tried? I can't really understand your question and what the problem is.

Comment: Hint:  consider the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: I tried that theorem but I got nothing.

Comment: it's not a clear question ,i see this question to be off-topic

Comment: I think the question is clear

Comment: guys, seriesly no one wants to help me???????????????

Comment: The answer is the lcm of the numbers $2$ to $11$. For  $x\equiv y\pmod{k}$ for every $k$ from $2$ to $11$ if and only if the lcm of these numbers divides $x-y$.

Comment: People are more inclined to help when they seem some level of effort in the question...

Comment: @DrXorile I really tried but I couldn't

Comment: If you just show what you tried, you'll have much more success asking

Comment: @DrXorile see my try

Comment: Good job! You got it

Comment: Oh, but is there any other way to solve it, and if there is, I want you to do it

Answer (score 1):

What you wan can be set up as:

$x\equiv1\bmod 2$

$x\equiv 1\bmod 3$

$x\equiv1\bmod 4$

$x\equiv 1\bmod 5$

$x\equiv1\bmod 6$

$x\equiv 1\bmod 7$

$x\equiv1\bmod 8$

$x\equiv 1\bmod 9$

$x\equiv1\bmod 10$

$x\equiv 1\bmod 11$

which is equivalent to

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 2^3$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 3^2$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 5$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 7$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 11$

which by CRT has unique solution $\bmod 2^3\cdot3^2\cdot 5\cdot 11$. The answer thus is $2^3\cdot3^2\cdot 5\cdot7 \cdot11$